# ColdFusion 10 server side redirects

Tags: tomcat, iis, iis-7, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am moving an application from ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 10 and I am having some strange behavior with server side redirects `getPageContext().forward()`.  The application is deployed on IIS with Halicon IIS rewrite module (http://www.isapirewrite.com/).  In CF9 trying to do a server side redirect to a url like `local.site.com/article/monday` works fine.  (The url is rewritten by url rewrites to actually go to something like `local.site.com/index.cfm?page=article&title=monday`.  But in CF10 I am not exactly sure what is happening but my pages are all coming in as `//index.cf`.  Any thoughts on what is happening?

Comment: Can you clarify; are you having issues with redirects using `getPageContext().forward()` or using IIS rewrite?  Or both?

Comment: I am only having issues with redirects using getPageContext().forward(). EG getPageContext().forward('local.site.com/article/monday') or getPageContext().forward('/index.cfm/stuff/morestuff/morestuff') comes through to my application.cfc with cgi.script_name as //index.cf

Comment: This is probably an issue with your IIS rewrite rules or some other configuration difference between your environments. ColdFusion is simply receiving what IIS and ISAPI Rewrite sent it. What version of ISAPI Rewrite are you using? Can you post your rewrite rule?

Comment: the rewrites work fine when coming through the browser

Comment: If it is an issue with the getPageContext().forward() method. You might try using a <cflocation> instead. Ben Nadel has some nice things to say about it here: [link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/382-Is-ColdFusion-s-GetPageContext-Forward-Method-Worth-Using-.htm)

Comment: cflocation and pageContext.forward behave different. cflocation doesn't suite my needs in this case.